# Writing/reading array to file

Tags: java, arrays, file, save

I have an app that will create 3 arrays : 2 with `double` values and one with strings that can contain anything,alphanumeric,commas,points,anything the user might want to type or type by accident. The `double` arrays are easy.The string one i find to be tricky.
It can contain stuff like `cake red,blue 1kg` `paper-clip`,you get the ideea.

I will need to store those arrays somehow(i guess in a file is the easiest way),read them and get them back into the app whenever the user wants to.

Also,it would be well if they wouldn't be human readable,to only be able to read them thru my app.

What's the best way to do this ? My issue is,how can i read them back into arrays.Its easy to write to a file but then to get them back in the same array i put them in...How can i separate array elements for it not to split one element in two because it has a `space` or any other element.

Can i like,make 3 rows of text,each element split by a tab `\t` or something and when i read it each element will by split by that tab ? Will this be able to create any issues when reading ?
I guess i want to know how can i split the elements of the array so that it won't be able to ever read them wrong.

Thanks and have a nice day !

Comment: you can use a special character for word separator

Comment: I might just store the data in JSON; or maybe I would use [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) or [SQLite](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc); I'd need to see a few more requirements to really decide.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the file to be human readable, you could use`java.io.RandomAccessFile`. 
You would probably want to specify a maximum string size if you did this.

To save a string:

```
String str = "hello";
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(new File("filename"));
final int MAX_STRING_BYTES = 100; // max number of bytes the string could use in the file   
file.writeUTF(str);
file.skipBytes(MAX_STRING_BYTES - str.getBytes().length);
// then write another..
```

To read a string:

```
// instantiate again
final int STRING_POSITION = 100; // or whichever place you saved it
file.seek(STRING_POSITION);
String str = new String(file.read(MAX_STRING_BYTES));
```

You would probably want a use the beginning of the file to store the size of each array. Then just store all the values one by one in the file, no need for separators.